# classic asp and hash tables, is there one?

Tags: asp-classic

Is there such a thing as a hashtable in classic asp?  Need to concatenate some data together and the only sensible way to do it would be via a hashtable.  Can't find anything on the web so I am guessing no, so what alternatives are there?

My apologies, its VB script - legacy site.

Thanks.

Comment: Your choice of language would be a handy addition to this question. Probably vbscript but could be js.

Comment: what are you doing? You might have better efficiency using JScript instead, it's possible to write JScript function and use it from within VBScript in the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using classic asp and vbscript, the closest thing is using a dictionary object.
Check out [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_dictionary.asp).

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. funny it didn't show up till after my edit!?

Comment: Thanks moriartyn that was they clue 'dictionary object' that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

as spender mentioned, jscript has had objects, that resemble hashtables enough to function as them, for many years.

---

and a little digging brings up the vbscript Dictionary object, which I'm pretty sure I used back in the mid-90s, another Hashtable workalike.